# Is there a use case for direct FileDescriptor instantiation?

Tags: java, file-descriptor

I am going through Java's API and wondering whether there a use case for creating a `FileDescriptor` object using the class's constructor - in other words:

```
FileDescriptor newFileDescriptor = new FileDescriptor();
```

The API specifies that the constructed object is invalid. Thanks.

Comment: well based off the API page, there are no other constructors so I'd say no.

Comment: FileDescriptor()
Constructs an (invalid) FileDescriptor object.

Comment: That's the description of the constructor from Javadoc

Comment: I've voted to close this as there is a good explanation why the constructor is there. It doesn't make sense to use it yourself, but that's stated directly in the JavaDoc of the class, it makes little sense to just re-iterate that here (unless we want to use StackOverflow as out of date JavaDoc reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I have not encountered a use case where this makes sense.

The [`FileDescriptor` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html) is pretty clear that while you *can* construct a `FileDescriptor` directly, *you should not*:

> Instances of the file descriptor class serve as an opaque handle to
>   the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file,
>   an open socket, or another source or sink of bytes. The main practical
>   use for a file descriptor is to create a FileInputStream or
>   FileOutputStream to contain it. Applications should not create their
>   own file descriptors.

Note the last sentence: *Applications should not create their own file descriptors.*

The [`FileDescriptor()` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#FileDescriptor()) explains further (as you found):

> Constructs an (invalid) FileDescriptor object.

Therefore, `newFileDescriptor.valid()` will return `false`.

*Having said this*, **if** you directly construct a `FileDescriptor`, it is certainly a valid *Java object* in the general sense.  For example, the following code...

```
FileDescriptor newFileDescriptor = new FileDescriptor();
System.out.println(newFileDescriptor.getClass());
```

...outputs...

> class java.io.FileDescriptor

...just as one would expect; but that is not particularly useful of course – for an object one would hope to use as a file descriptor.

Bottom line, hair-splitting aside, it is best to follow the documentation's advice.

Comment: Thanks. So I assume that invalid in the case of the Descriptor is regards to functionality. not existence?

Comment: @user3814660: Right, existent but invalid for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#FileDescriptor()) says

> Applications should not create their own file descriptors.

That seems pretty clear.

The only constructor's documentation says

> Constructs an (invalid) FileDescriptor object.

which also seems fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks. Just wanted to know if anyone has worked with an exception to that rule.

Answer (score -1):

so you want get acess to some files right ? have a look : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/filedescriptor/java-file-descriptor-example/
Basically, Java class FileDescriptor provides a handle to the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file, an open socket, or another source or sink of bytes.

The applications should not create FileDescriptor objects, they are mainly used in creation of FileInputStream or FileOutputStream objects to contain it.

So, whenever we create a FileInputStream or FileOutputStream object we get a FileDescriptor object associated with it, we can also use this FileDescriptor object to create another FileInputStream or FileOutputStream object.

Now, Lets see the example of FileInputStream with FileDescriptor.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(

                "/path/to/file.txt"));

        FileDescriptor fd = fileInputStream.getFD();

        System.out.println(" File descriptor of the file/path/to/file.txt : "
                        + fd.hashCode());

        fileInputStream.close();

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(

                "/path/to/file.txt"));

        FileDescriptor fd2 = fileOutputStream.getFD();



        fileOutputStream.close();

    }
```